# C# Collection select value of the property with minimum value of another property

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

So let's say I have a type `Car` with two properties `Speed` and `Color`

```
public class Car
{
   public int Speed {get; set;}
   public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

Using LINQ I may find the minimum speed

```
int minSpeed = collection.Min(em => em.Speed);
```

so minSpeed will contain the value of speed of the car with the minimum speed in collection.

But how can I do something similar to get the color of the car?

Something like:

```
string color = collection.Min(em => em.Speed).Select(x => x.Color);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [MinBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs).

```
Car slowestCar = collection.MinBy(em => em.Speed);
string color = slowestCar.Color;
```

Comment: @Joper: No, there is nothing similar built-in to the framework. Also, it's not sugar.

Comment: You could subsitute it for 'collection.OrderBy(em => em.Speed).First()`, but note that is an O(n log n) algorithm rather than MinBy which is O(n); it has to sort the entire collection, instead of just going through it once.

Comment: And BTW MinBy will probably make it to the framework eventually, as it is part of the recent Interactive Extensions release: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26651

Comment: @gunr2171: Just found where it should be now and updated the linq (sic - gettit?).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<string> color = collection.Where(x=> x.Speed == collection.Min(em => em.Speed)).Select(x => x.Color).Distinct();
```

Of course, you can have several cars with same minimum speed, so you get IEnumerable.